# Reference to the Previous Question on Why VBA is not loading all the Invoice details

Tags: json, vba

Addition to the prior question, we still have the same loading failure issue on the sales invoices:

The VBA/Json below still load only one row or the first product details line instead of all products lines details partnering to that sales invoice in the table

We want The VBA below to be able to load the invoice detail as per parameter:
Example if we have invoice number 0001 with the following details:

```
Invoice Header
--------------------------
Inv Number 0001
Date : 2019-10-10
Customer Name: Lukas
Address : USA

Line Details
--------------------------------------------------
(1) Apple    Qty (20)  Unit cost(5) Total (100)
(2) Orange   Qty (30)  Unit cost(5) Total (600)
(3) Lemonade Qty (40)  Unit cost(5) Total (800)
```

The above detail must all show up in Json NOT only the first item

```
Private Sub CmdSales_Click()

'  Const SQL_SELECT As String = "SELECT * FROM Qry3;"

  Dim coll As VBA.Collection
  Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim fld As DAO.Field
  Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
  Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
  Dim root As Dictionary
    Set root = New Dictionary

    Dim transaction As Dictionary
    Dim transactions As Collection
    Dim item As Dictionary
    Dim items As Collection
    Dim invoice As Dictionary
    Dim invoices As Collection

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Set transactions = New Collection
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Qry4")
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm = Eval(prm.Name)
Next prm
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset()

Set qdf = Nothing
 rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Set transaction = New Dictionary
        transaction.Add "PosSerialNumber", DLookup("PosSerialNumber", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv)
        transaction.Add "IssueTime", DLookup("IssueTime", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv)
        transaction.Add "Customer", DLookup("CustomerName", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv)
        transaction.Add "TransactionTyp", 0
        transaction.Add "PaymentMode", 0
        transaction.Add "SaleType", 0

        '--- loop over all the items
        Dim itemCount As Long
        itemCount = 2
        Set items = New Collection
        For i = 1 To itemCount
            Set item = New Dictionary
            item.Add "ItemID", i
            item.Add "Description", DLookup("Description", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv)
            item.Add "BarCode", DLookup("BarCode", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv)
            item.Add "Quantity", DLookup("Qty", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv)
            item.Add "UnitPrice", DLookup("unitPrice", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv)
            item.Add "Discount", DLookup("Discount", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv)

            '--- loop over all the invoices
            Dim invoiceCount As Long
            invoiceCount = 3
            Set invoices = New Collection
            For j = 1 To invoiceCount
                Set invoice = New Dictionary
                invoice.Add "Total", DLookup("TotalAmount", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv) + j
                invoice.Add "IsTaxInclusive", DLookup("Inclusive", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv)
                invoice.Add "RRP", DLookup("RRP", "Qry4", "Inv =" & Me.CboInv)
                invoices.Add invoice
            Next j
            item.Add "Taxable", invoices
            items.Add item
        Next i
        transaction.Add "Items", items
        transactions.Add transaction
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    root.Add "JSON Created", Now()
    root.Add "Transactions", transactions

    Dim json As String
    json = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(root, Whitespace:=3)
    Debug.Print json

End Sub
```

Current results from the above code:

```
{
   "JSON Created": "2019-10-10",
   "Transactions": [
      {
         "PosSerialNumber": "102010",
         "IssueTime": "2019-09-15",
         "Customer": "J J Zingalume",
         "TransactionTyp": 0,
         "PaymentMode": 0,
         "SaleType": 0,
         "Items": [
            {
               "ItemID": 1,
               "Description": "Apple (Rgb 350 ML)",
               "BarCode": "6009803227328",
               "Quantity": 15,
               "UnitPrice": 41,
               "Discount": 0,
               "Taxable": [
                  {
                     "Total": 616,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  },
                  {
                     "Total": 617,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  },
                  {
                     "Total": 618,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "ItemID": 2,
               "Description": "Apple (Rgb 350 ML)",
               "BarCode": "6009803227328",
               "Quantity": 15,
               "UnitPrice": 41,
               "Discount": 0,
               "Taxable": [
                  {
                     "Total": 616,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  },
                  {
                     "Total": 617,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  },
                  {
                     "Total": 618,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "PosSerialNumber": "102010",
         "IssueTime": "2019-09-15",
         "Customer": "J J Zingalume",
         "TransactionTyp": 0,
         "PaymentMode": 0,
         "SaleType": 0,
         "Items": [
            {
               "ItemID": 1,
               "Description": "Apple (Rgb 350 ML)",
               "BarCode": "6009803227328",
               "Quantity": 15,
               "UnitPrice": 41,
               "Discount": 0,
               "Taxable": [
                  {
                     "Total": 616,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  },
                  {
                     "Total": 617,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  },
                  {
                     "Total": 618,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "ItemID": 2,
               "Description": "Apple (Rgb 350 ML)",
               "BarCode": "6009803227328",
               "Quantity": 15,
               "UnitPrice": 41,
               "Discount": 0,
               "Taxable": [
                  {
                     "Total": 616,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  },
                  {
                     "Total": 617,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  },
                  {
                     "Total": 618,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "PosSerialNumber": "102010",
         "IssueTime": "2019-09-15",
         "Customer": "J J Zingalume",
         "TransactionTyp": 0,
         "PaymentMode": 0,
         "SaleType": 0,
         "Items": [
            {
               "ItemID": 1,
               "Description": "Apple (Rgb 350 ML)",
               "BarCode": "6009803227328",
               "Quantity": 15,
               "UnitPrice": 41,
               "Discount": 0,
               "Taxable": [
                  {
                     "Total": 616,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  },
                  {
                     "Total": 617,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  },
                  {
                     "Total": 618,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "ItemID": 2,
               "Description": "Apple (Rgb 350 ML)",
               "BarCode": "6009803227328",
               "Quantity": 15,
               "UnitPrice": 41,
               "Discount": 0,
               "Taxable": [
                  {
                     "Total": 616,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  },
                  {
                     "Total": 617,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  },
                  {
                     "Total": 618,
                     "IsTaxInclusive": "True",
                     "RRP": 52.8
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

All Invoice detail must be appearing as per Parameter query

Comment: why don't you use some breakpoints and `Debug.Print` to work out what's going on in your code. This would be much faster than us trying to work through your slab of code

Comment: When you assign item (and invoice values for that matter), you are looking up based only on `Me.CboInv` and this never changes does it? So you just get the same line over and over. You need to also be looking up based on `i`, however you have limited this to two lines only.

Comment: So, assuming you have an item line number, you need to add that filter to your `DLookup`

Comment: Okay I can debug.print , but my question is where I'm going wrong here? And what is the solution to this? The item number I have but how to put in the dlookup?

Comment: How did you filter on `Me.CboInv` in the `Dlookup`? I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

(multiple lines for clarity)

```
item.Add 
    "Description", 
    DLookup(
        "Description", 
        "Qry4", 
        "Inv =" & Me.CboInv & " AND LineItemID = " & CStr(i)
    )
```

Note the filter argument also includes `i`

```
"Inv =" & Me.CboInv & " AND LineItemID = " & CStr(i)
```

`CStr` converts a number to a string.

I'm assuming your line item id column is called `LineItemID`. It's not clear from your question whether you even have a lineitemid column

Comment: Now I can see line 2 but line 3 is still missing , then total are also incorrect ,its now adding 1,2,3 per each total. Kindly note that the totals are supposed to be at the end of each product . Not all three totals per product as per product total and repeating themselves several times. IS IT POSSIBLE TO THIS APPLICATION ONLINE FOR EASY REFERENCING? However , you are almost sorting it out!

Comment: Okay now all the three products are there, the only problem is that it prints the same products 3 times just because they are 3 , the parameter query is working fine,is there a way to stop this , And the json header with the date on top is not required.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense to me. Are you saying that all line items have the same lineitemid? Please edit your question and post a sample of what is actually in `Qry4` with column names. ALso please refer consistently to the things in this question. Is a product the same as a line item?